# highlight span tag content line by line in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I used these lines of code for highlighting my sentences,every thins is OK but i want to highlight line by line(this code highlight all lines in span tag together)

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var seconds = 5;
  var el = $('span#test');
  var width = el.outerWidth();
  var height = el.outerHeight();
  var wrapper = $('<span>').css({
    width: width + 'px',
    height: height + 'px',
    position: 'relative'
  });
  var background = $('<span>').css({
    width: 0,
    height: height + 'px',
    position: 'absolute',
    background: '#0f0'
  });
  wrapper.append(background);
  wrapper.append(el.css('position','absolute'));
  $('body').append(wrapper);
  background.animate({width: '+=' + width},1000*seconds);

});​
```

How can i do it?

I know i can do it by splitting it's to chars(**like this:** [Highligh Line By Line](http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/34/)) but i used custom font.

**my Demo:**http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/41/

please help!

Comment: What's the problem if you're using a custom font?

Comment: -@Ofir Baruch:i can not split line into char when i using custom font.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to use the :first-line selector and a buffer but unfortunately this selector is not available in jQuery/Sizzle, so I came up with another solution to split the lines in a `span` based on that `span`'s width. It makes use of the Canvas 2D API though.

The basic approach to solving your problem is to use `$.fn.animate()` per line, e.g. applying the animations with a start delay for each line like this:

```
// apply animation per line (fading out as example)
$('span .line').each(function(idx) 
{
    $(this).wrap('<span class="linecontent">');
    $(this).delay(idx * 1500).fadeOut(1500);
});
```

Splitting a paragraph into lines presents a problem when using javascript. The solution I applied is based on separating words using RegEx word boundaries, this will present a problem if there is any other content to be wrapped than pure text. Any non-whitespace Unicode character should be recognized as part of a word though.

Here's the word separation code (expecting text content in a span):

```
// split words
words = ($('span').text().split(/\W/));
lineWidth = $('span').width() - 80; // security offset

canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

$(canvas).css(
{
    'height': $('span').height(),
    'width': lineWidth
});
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = $('span').css('font');

line = []; 
lines = [];

while (words.length > 0)
{
    metrics = ctx.measureText(line.join(' '));

    if (metrics.width < lineWidth) 
    {
        line.push(words.shift());         
    } else 
    {
        lines.push(line);
        line = [];
    }
}

$('span').empty();
sp = $('span');
$(lines).each(function() 
{
    l = $('<span class="line">').append(this.join(' '));
    $(l).css('display', 'inline-block');
    $(sp).append(l);
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvz5Z/2/) that demonstrates this line separation and applying a fade out animation to each line. It should be no problem to adapt the highlighting code from your fiddle to be working on the `span.line` elements and to use the animation delays, also using custom fonts should not present a problem since the Canvas API afaik accepts this gracefully. But there is, as mentioned above, one catch: The word separation.

Comment: exactly your idea is true but i want to highlight each line from first to end and each span tag highlight must finish in special time(for example 20 sec)i want to do some thing like this:http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/34/